# Not able to connect to DB if tried to load the connection string from secure vault

Tags: mule, database-connection, mule-component, cloudhub

if I place the DB connection string in secure vault and deploy that on cloud hub , I am getting Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out" ,exception and i am not able to connect to DB .

surprisingly , If i place the same property in plain properties file its working fine .

What is happening here ? pls advise me if anybody has encountered the same issue

Thanks
Naveen H

Comment: Did you get a chance to debug the code? or post some code. Your question is lacking details..

Comment: bedug the cloud in cloudHub ? its working fine in local

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the property is not being set correctly. You didn't share any details on what secure method are you using and the exact configuration to be more precise. Try using the plain configuration in the DB config and print the secure one in a logger, to see if they match.